# Preserving versioning between SharePoint 2003 and 2010

Tags: document-library, migration, document-set

I am in the final stage of document transfer for our 2010 site before it goes live. I have been able to set up network connections between the two libraries and was able to move (not copy) documents over. However, contrary to what I understand, the documents are not being moved with the version history. I suspect this has something to do with the differences between the versioning settings. Does anyone have a good solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can preserve your version history in one of two ways:

1) Upgrade your content databases to 2007 and then to 2010 so you retain your site content.

-or-

2) Use a third-party migration solution to do the copying with the version history.

Comment: These are great solutions that I have already considered. However, we do not have a legal version of SharePoint 2007 nor have I been able to find a third-party migration tool that supports SharePoint 2003.

Comment: Metalogix (one of my favorites) supports 2003 as a source system: http://www.metalogix.com/Products/Content-Matrix/Tech-Specs.aspx

Comment: And you can use a trial version of SharePoint 2007: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24264

Comment: I ended up using Metologix. It worked perfect.